# C# - var not behaving as expected in for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, long-integer, var

I found a situation where using "var" caused unexpected results.

In the code below I was expecting X to be declared as datatype "long".

Why does X get declared as datatype "int" ? (which causes an infinite loop in this case)

```
long maxNumber = (long)int.MaxValue + 1;
long count = 0;

for (var X = 0; X < maxNumber; X++)
{
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, that is allowed by the rules, but I would edit, rephrase it as a question, and post your answer to it, and mark it as accepted.

Comment: The type for the `var` is inferred by declaration. The literal `0` is an integer. Therefore your `var` is an integer. There's no way for the compiler to infer how you're going to use that `var` later. If you want a long, you have to use the proper literal `0L`.

Comment: @eddie_cat Good guideline, but let's not worry over Jeapordy-esque semantics. I, for one, thought the implied query was pretty clear. (ie, "Can someone explain this?")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var X = 0
```

This is the line that declares X's type, regardless of how it's later used. When you specify a numerical literal without any suffixes, it will be an integer. Here's one possible solution.

```
var X = 0L
```

Answer (score 4):

And why did you expect

```
var X = 0;
```

to infer datatype `long`?

Type inference for `var` variables looks at the type of the initial value, only.  It doesn't consider usage.

Others are telling you how to control the type of `0`, with a suffix.  I say, if you want a particular type, go ahead and write

```
long X = 0;
```

This isn't really the sweet spot for `var`.  Type inference is mainly for types which are hard to name (`IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Converter<TreeViewNode, IEnumerable<TreeViewNode>>>>` anyone?) or can't be named at all, in the case of anonymous types, or if you want the type to automatically change to match the return type of some other function.  Integral loop counters just don't benefit.